# View that displays both Media files and nodes

Tags: 7, views, media

I have run into a problem where it seems like you can't display Media module Files alongside regular nodes. I have a filter that is set to show content of type Webform. I wanted to be able to have an OR operator and show Files of type Document (plus a tag of type "form") so I could show "paper" forms with web forms, but alas, it doesn't appear possible. This filter option

[image]

isn't present unless I choose "Files" when setting up a new view

[image]

Some magic must be happening when "Files" is chosen, but it isn't apparent to me.

Comment: Same happens if you try to show taxonomy terms along with regular nodes. I'm not shure if this can be solved. At least this might be solved in D8 since everything is an entity.

Comment: Interesting. I think one workaround would be to make a separate view with the files and attach one to the other, but then they aren't integrated.